# jQuery - How to detect when page is finished loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I detect if the page is finished loading completely? I say completely because I tried putting an alert statement in the `$(document).ready(function()` code, but the alert statement happens before the wheel stops spinning in IE (After like 1.5 seconds, the wheel stops, and that's when the page is completely loaded). (its the loading wheel you see in the top of IE9 where the tab is).

Thanks

Comment: also you can put your function on particular element like `<body onload='loadfunction()'> </body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now use
`$(window).on('load', function(){ ...});`

Below is deprecated and may give "Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function" error

```
$(window).load(function() {
// do stuff 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `load` method:

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).load(function() {
// do stuff 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload) event.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //....
});
```

The `document ready` event executes already when the HTML-Document is loaded and the DOM is ready, even if all the graphics haven’t loaded yet and the `window load` event executes a bit later when the complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images.

Comment: and how can find out that a specific div content loaded ? is something like this: $('#mydiv').load(function(){...}); ?

Comment: If you are using `jQuery` then you can check this like `if($('#mydiv').length){ //do something }`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){});
```

Above function guarantees that the DOM is ready to be modified by javascript. It does not guarantees about the xhr request which are asynchronous in nature to load.SO there might be situation that some xhr request is happening and the spinner shows loading untill there is no http request in progress.